# Accelerate query regarding date variable

Tags: postgresql

I need to query data generated in yesterday every morning using a script.

The query is like

```
select xxx 
from table 
where create_time >= current_date - 1 
  and create_time < current_date 
limit 10;
```

Its query plan is:

```
                   QUERY PLAN                                     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=100.00..117.64 rows=3 width=138)
   ->  Foreign Scan on table  (cost=100.00..117.64 rows=3 width=138)
```

The query above takes extremely long.

However when I use fixed time as shown below, it returns results immediately...

```
select xxx 
from table 
where create_time >= '2020-07-30 00:00:00' 
  and create_time < '2020-08-03 00:00:00' 
limit 10;
```

Its query plan is:
10;

```
                                       QUERY PLAN                                       
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=100.00..131.46 rows=3 width=138)
   ->  Foreign Scan on table (cost=100.00..131.46 rows=3 width=138)
         Filter: ((create_time < CURRENT_DATE) AND (create_time >= (CURRENT_DATE - 1)))
```

What makes this difference? And how to accelerate the 1st query?

Comment: It would have been more helpful to see the execution plans generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** to see the actual runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `table` is a **foreign table**. The Postgres foreign data wrapper can't push down the expression `current_date - 1` to the foreign server, because the server might have a different idea on what `current_date` is, then the server where you run the query. So it has to fetch **all** rows from the remote server and do the filtering on the server where you run the query.

The constant value can be pushed down to the foreign server, so that only the rows are returned (and send of the network) that qualify the condition (most likely using an index).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
select xxx 
from table 
where create_time >= (select current_date - 1)
  and create_time < (select current_date)
limit 10;
```

maybe this will be faster